# minimum image dimension (w*h) too small in the dataset for it to use as target_size in Keras CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have very robust data in my dataset varies in dimensions, intensity,flip, shear etc. By using,

```
from PIL import Image
mini = 99999

for _,_,files in os.walk(train_dir):
    print(len(files))
for pic in files:
    with Image.open(train_dir+pic) as img:
        width, height = img.size
        if min(width,height)<mini:
            mini = min(height,width)
print(mini)
```

it prints `19996, 8` and it means that either the minimum of height or width of all the images is 8. So can I use

`ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_dataframe(target_size=(8,8) )`. I think it won't be a good idea to use this. and if not (8,8) what should I use? I am using the data for Convolution Neural Networks for Age Detection in Keras using Tensorflow as backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, do this instead:

```
min_w, min_h = 10000, 10000
for pic in files:
    with Image.open(train_dir+pic) as img:
        width, height = img.size
        min_w = min( min_w, width)
        min_h = min( min_h, height)

print(min_w, min_h)
```

Then you will have at least reasonable understanding about the smallest image size.

Regarding the second part of your question -- NO, target size of the image of 8x8 is too small to do anything meaningful, so you may want to discard the images that are too small or upscale them or do something else, depending on the data contents.

I would consider the image size about 100x100 ~ 200x200 a good size for practicing with CNN in Keras.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking about but it did not make any difference as it just gave me (8,11) so I'll just go with (150,150) to be on the safe side.